# Efficient way to count NaN columns across all rows of a large pandas dataset?

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

I'm currently counting the number of missing columns across my full dataset with:

```
missing_cols = X.apply(lambda x: x.shape[0] - x.dropna().shape[0], axis=1).value_counts().to_frame()
```

When I run this, my RAM usage dramatically increases. In Kaggle, it's enough to crash the machine. After the operation and a `gc.collect()`, I don't seem to get all of the memory back, hinting at some sort of leak.

[image: Maxed out]

I'm trying to get a feel for the number of rows missing 1 column of data, 2 columns of data, 3 columns of data, etc.

Is there a more efficient way to perform this calculation?

Comment: all value in columns is nan? or do you want count NaN values by rows?

Comment: @lostCode In the end, I'm producing a bar chart -- % of dataset missing 1 column (a null value found on any col.) % of dataset missing 2 columns, up to % of dataset missing all columns. So, I'm trying to produce a table sized `len(X.columns)` and a value for the # of rows missing that many column's worth of data. I sketched up a solution using iloc, but it was ridiculously slow. Going through the dataset with iterrows seemed to run out of memory even quicker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to get the output you would get with your code you could use:

```
df.isnull().sum(axis=1).value_counts().to_frame()
```

This is an example:

```
df=pd.DataFrame()
df['col1']=[np.nan,1,3,5,np.nan]
df['col2']=[2,np.nan,np.nan,3,6]
df['col3']=[1,3,np.nan,4,np.nan]
print(df)
print(df.isnull().sum(axis=1))
print(df.isnull().sum(axis=0))


   col1  col2  col3
0   NaN   2.0   1.0
1   1.0   NaN   3.0
2   3.0   NaN   NaN
3   5.0   3.0   4.0
4   NaN   6.0   NaN
0    1
1    1
2    2
3    0
4    2
dtype: int64
col1    2
col2    2
col3    2
dtype: int64
```

**as you can see you can get the count of NaN values ​​by rows and by columns**

Now doing:

```
df.isnull().sum(axis=1).value_counts().to_frame()

   0
2  2
1  2
0  1
```

Comment: Very nice! I started with a very similar function, but I was using a `.apply`, which was the problem, blowing up the RAM. https://i.imgur.com/OMyflUw.png

Answer (score 0):

You can count `na` values by row using the following:

```
df.isna().count(axis='rows')
```

If this is causing your machine to crash, I would suggest iterating chunk-wise.